# Using FFT to efficiently multiply multiple polynomials modulo N

Tags: polynomials, fast-fourier-transform

I have a set of polynomials $P_k$ defined as:

$$
P_k = \sum_{n = 0}^{n = N} p_{kn} x^n
$$

$N$ is large ($2^{16}$)

I would like to perform multiplication on the polynomials:

$$
Q = \prod_{k=0}^{k=K} P_k
$$

$K = 16$

But I only want to keep the coefficients from $0$ to $N$ i.e.

$$
Q = \sum_{n = 0}^{n = N} q_nx^n
$$

I know the fastest way to multiply two large polynomials is using the FFT to perform linear convolution by zero padding the two polynomials by N before taking the forward transform, point wise multiplying and then taking the inverse transform. However, for $K$ polynomials I would have to pad $K*N$. Is there an efficient method where I can pad by N, do the forward transform on all the polynomials, and just take one inverse transform at the end?

Comment: Have a look at Karatsuba algorithm (https://mathstrek.blog/2012/10/08/polynomial-multiplication-karatsuba-and-fast-fourier-transform/).

Comment: @JeanMarie, ideally, I don't want the efficiency of the algorithm to be less than (K + 1) * N log N which is K forward FFT and one inverse FFT.